# How to update a timestamp as the current time, less the id field in seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I'm trying to add a timestamp field (added) to users (userstest in this case) table and need it to be roughly in order for existing users. The date for existing users doesn't matter so much, however the order is important.

I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE  userstest SET added =  TIMESTAMP( NOW( ) - id );
```

However many of the results are just setting themselves to "2014-01-30 19:03:31" (all the same value), which should not be the case as since the id is unique, the time should also be unique.

I have 2,725 records if it makes any difference.

What exactly am I missing here that is causing this to work not as I expected?

**ANSWER:** Thanks to the 3 very helpful people in the comments

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval id SECOND
```

Ok, it seems this is the right way to do it, however my original math did have a logic issue as well, it should have been:

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval (3523902 - id) SECOND
```

Otherwise the order is reversed. 3523902 being the highest ID of all the records.

Comment: Define the interval: `UPDATE  userstest SET added = NOW( ) - interval id seconds`

Comment: Use intervals instead of just a subtraction. ^ beat me to it.

Comment: `SET added = TIMESTAMP(NOW() - id)`?? For the first person (id=1), `added = TIMESTAMP(now() - 1)` and for the latest person, (id=1000 for example), `added = TIMESTAMP(now - 1000)` - You are assigning a prior date to each newer person! I have to say this- the logic is totally wrong!!

Comment: @juergend Thanks, that was greatly helpful, though I found it to be second, not seconds.

Comment: @Rachcha Yes, you are right, I discovered that after I ran it, and so I subtracted the id from the highest existing ID rectifying the issue. Thanks for noting it =]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. One of the points of this system is to gather a collection of good questions ( which yours is ) and their answers. Please write an answer to your question rather than just editing your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the 3 very helpful people in the comments of the original question.

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval id SECOND
```

Ok, it seems this is the right way to do it, however my original math did have a logic issue as well, it should have been:

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval (3523902 - id) SECOND
```

Otherwise the order is reversed. 3523902 being the highest ID of all the records so that the date of the newest record would be set as the time the SQL query was run and each prior record would count backwards from that time.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

A fast way to do it (if you dont realy care abaut what time its and you only whant the order) is using `from_unixtime`:

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = from_unixtime(id)

UPDATE userstest SET added = from_unixtime(3523902 - id) #reversed order
```

---

From question:

ANSWER: Thanks to the 3 very helpful people in the comments

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval id SECOND
```

Ok, it seems this is the right way to do it, however my original math did have a logic issue as well, it should have been:

```
UPDATE userstest SET added = NOW() - interval (3523902 - id) SECOND
```

Otherwise the order is reversed. 3523902 being the highest ID of all the records.